# How to properly set up "responsive" jquery events

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a little function I build to account for the even stacking of a grid of objects that vary in height. The issue is that my jquery is unnecessary and problematic on a mobile/stacked layout.

As far as I can tell, I'm using this correctly but it's not working.

Any help?

On desktop (> 480) the command under `else` fires too instead of just what's under `if`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ( $(window).width() < 480) {     

    // Get an array of all element heights
    var elementHeights = $('.box').map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
    }).get();

    // Math.max takes a variable number of arguments
    // `apply` is equivalent to passing each height as an argument
    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, elementHeights);

    // Set each height to the max height
    $('.box').height(maxHeight);

}
else if ( $(window).width() > 480) {

    $('.box').css("height", "auto");

}

});
```

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/jeremypbeasley/pen/bnfmD

Comment: Why aren't you using `else` instead of `else if`?

Comment: In the same line as what @bencripps says, if the display is 480px (e.g.: WP8) nothing is done. You should be using if...else...